# Centering a UL with fixed width LIs in div with dynamic width

Tags: html, css

I have scoured the web for an answer to this one, but to no avail.

Is it possible to center a UL which contains fixed width LIs in a DIV with 100% width?

```
<div style="width:100%;max-width:1400px;">
    <ul>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
    </ul>
```

It is important that the LIs are NOT centered within the UL.

EDIT: The width of the UL must also have dynamic width in order to fill the dynamic width DIV.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Do you want the li elements to be in a row or column?

Comment: In a row (which automatically becomes 2 or more rows when the div is smaller than 7x280px).

Answer (score 0):

The `ul`, by default, is also 100% wide.
To center it inside the surrounding div, you need to set a `width` to the ul.

Here's an example:

```
<div style="width:100%;max-width:1400px;">
    <ul style="width: 300px; left: 50%; margin-left: -150px;">
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
        <li style="width:280px;height:280px;>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Note, that the `margin-left` of the ul is half it's `width`.

Answer (score 0):

What about that

```
<div style="width:100%;max-width:1400px;">
<ul style="margin:auto; width:280px">
    <li style="height:280px;>d</li>
    <li style="height:280px;>d</li>
    <li style="height:280px;>d</li>
    <li style="height:280px;>d</li>
    <li style="height:280px;>d</li>
    <li style="height:280px;>d</li>
    <li style="height:280px;>d</li>
</ul>
</div>e
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding a class to your ul, such as

`ul .centerUL { 
width:500px; 
margin:0 auto; #centers an element
}`